# When I load the datetime column into snowflake I see 10 and 11-hour differences

Tags: datetime, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to combine two columns with date and time data in the ETL tool and load them into snowflake. When I load the data as datetime, there are 10 and 11 hour differences. At the same time, I share with you the current hours of Snowflake and my local.

```
select current_timestamp >> '2022-11-15 23:46:47.318 -0800'
My current hour is now >> '2022-11-16 10:46:47.318'
```

The photo below will help to understand the problem more closely. STAGE_DATE Merged version of VBRK_FKDAT and VBRK_ERZET. I want to see this date. I combine VBRK_FKDAT and VBRK_ERZET from Data Services and after I get 10 hours I send snowflake. This stands for INVOICEDATE. When I take the difference of INVOICEDATE and STAGE_DATE I get HOURDIFF. Randomly there are 10 and 11 hours difference. I'm trying to understand the problem.

Thank you for your interest.

[image: Datetime Issue]

Answer (score 0):

What you've explained is most probably related to the current setting for the **TIMEZONE**:

```
Default: America/Los_Angeles
```

The timestamps are stored internally in UTC but are displayed for the user based on the **TIMESTAMP** parameter value for session/user/account.

For more information have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#timezone).